# Splash Screen in GTK

Tags: c, gtk, splash-screen

I'm new to GTK and i'm using it to create UI in C. I've created a splash screen and i'm able to close it after specified seconds using the function `g_timeout_add(100, function_to_call, NULL);`. The Splash screen works great. but the problem is when in extend my program further (i.e) After closing the splash screen I want another window to be displayed automatically, it doesn't happen so. Both the windows open together. Here is my program.

```
gboolean function_to_call(gpointer data){
    gtk_quit_main();
    return(FALSE);
}
int main (int argc, char *argv[]){
    GtkWidget *window, *image, *another_window;
    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    g_timeout_add (100, function_to_call, NULL);
    gtk_main ();
    /*if my program is till this, splash screen closes after 1 sec . But when i try
     *to define another window from here onwards and call gtk_widget_show() and gtk_main() 
     *again for another_ window, window and another_window both open together and window  
     *doesn't close after 1 sec. */
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciatable.
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your function_to_call doesn't close your splash window here, it ends the gtk_main event loop. You don't need to end the event loop.

What you want to do instead, in your `function_to_call`, is hide (or destroy) your splash window and show your next window (`gtk_widget_hide()`,`gtk_widget_show()`).

Answer (score 2):

I've created a splashscreen header file which is shown below..

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/* Close the splash screen */
gboolean close_screen(gpointer data)
{
  gtk_widget_destroy((GtkWidget*)data);
  gtk_main_quit ();
  return(FALSE);
}


int Show_Splash_Screen(char* image_name,int time,int width,int height)
{
  GtkWidget  *image, *window;
  window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_widget_set_size_request (window, width, height);
  gtk_window_set_decorated(GTK_WINDOW (window), FALSE);
  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
  gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE);
  image=gtk_image_new_from_file(image_name);
  gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), image);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  g_timeout_add (time, close_screen, window);
  gtk_main ();
  return 0;
}
```

just include this file and to show a splash screen call the function 
Show_Splash_Screen("image_path",time_in_seconds,width_of_image_in_pixels,height_of_image_in_pixels);

Comment: Better use  gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
and also add  gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW(window),GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN);

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion... Made the required changes.. But could not get the idea of why to use gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW(window),GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN) ?? .. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Will a solution like this just delay making the app start up?  For my project, I need a splash screen that just displays until the app has finished loading/setting up.  I don't want to take up any extra time just to show the splash screen.

Comment: @gonzobrains yes it just delays the app startup. For your case dont set the timeout function, instead call the close screen function when you are done loading!